# C# IUnitOfWork, IRepository and IMemoryCache [ASP.Net Core]

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

My goal is to put in cache my data. I used [AspBoilerPlate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) as an inspiration for my code.

My WebApi use Asp.net Core.

**GitHub**

I created a branch on my GitHub for more details:

- [CacheRepository](https://github.com/ranouf/AspNetCore-Angular-AllInOne/tree/Caching/src/common/AllInOne.Common/Repositories/Cache)
- [CacheUnitOfWork](https://github.com/ranouf/AspNetCore-Angular-AllInOne/tree/Caching/src/common/AllInOne.Common/UnitOWork/Cache)

**CacheRepository**

```
public class CacheRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : Repository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>, ICacheRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
  where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public CacheRepository(DbContext dbContext, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        : base(dbContext)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public override TEntity FirstOrDefault(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(GetCacheKey(id), out TEntity result))
        {
            result = base.FirstOrDefault(id);
            if (result != null)
            {
                PutInCache(result);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void Delete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        foreach (var entity in GetAll().Where(predicate).ToList())
        {
            Delete(entity);
        }
    }

    public override void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        base.Delete(entity);
        RemoveFromCache(entity.Id);
    }

    public override void Delete(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        base.Delete(id);
        RemoveFromCache(id);
    }

    public override Task DeleteAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Delete(predicate));
    }

    public override Task DeleteAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Delete(entity));
    }

    public override Task DeleteAsync(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Delete(id));
    }

    public override Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        return _memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(
            GetCacheKey(id),
            e => base.FirstOrDefaultAsync(id)
        );
    }

    public override List<TEntity> GetAllList()
    {
        var entities = GetAllEntitiesFromCache();
        if (entities == null)
        {
            entities = base.GetAllList();
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                PutInCache(entity);
            }
        }

        return entities.ToList();
    }

    public override async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllListAsync()
    {
        var entities = GetAllEntitiesFromCache();
        if (entities == null)
        {
            entities = await base.GetAllListAsync();
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                PutInCache(entity);
            }
        }

        return entities.ToList();
    }

    public override TEntity Get(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        return _memoryCache.GetOrCreate(
            GetCacheKey(id),
            e => base.Get(id)
        );
    }

    public override Task<TEntity> GetAsync(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        return _memoryCache.GetOrCreate(
            GetCacheKey(id),
            e => base.GetAsync(id)
        );
    }

    public override TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        return PutInCache(base.Insert(entity));
    }

    public override TPrimaryKey InsertAndGetId(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Insert(entity).Id;
    }

    public override Task<TPrimaryKey> InsertAndGetIdAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(InsertAndGetId(entity));
    }

    public override Task<TEntity> InsertAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Insert(entity));
    }

    public override TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        return UpdateInCache(base.Update(entity));
    }

    public override TEntity Update(TPrimaryKey id, Action<TEntity> updateAction)
    {
        return UpdateInCache(base.Update(id, updateAction));
    }

    public override Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Update(entity));
    }

    public override async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TPrimaryKey id, Func<TEntity, Task> updateAction)
    {
        return UpdateInCache(await base.UpdateAsync(id, updateAction));
    }

    #region Private

    private TEntity PutInCache(TEntity entity)
    {
        return _memoryCache.Set(GetCacheKey(entity.Id), entity);
    }

    private void RemoveFromCache(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        _memoryCache.Remove(GetCacheKey(id));
    }

    private TEntity UpdateInCache(TEntity entity)
    {
        RemoveFromCache(entity.Id);
        return PutInCache(entity);
    }



    private string GetCacheKey(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        return typeof(TEntity).FullName + id;
    }

    private IList<TEntity> GetAllEntitiesFromCache()
    {
        return _memoryCache.Get<List<TEntity>>(typeof(TEntity));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**My questions:**

I have so many questions to ask about my CacheRepository, but I had to reduce it to be able to have my post published.

=> Is it a good thing to directly add/edit/delete in CacheRepository on Insert/Edit/Delete before the UnitOfWork.SubmitChanges?

If you have recommendation or suggestion about CacheRepository, please share it, I really want to learn more about that.

Comment: Without understanding the purpose of this (nor wanting to know) I can only suggest you look into using the EF Core in-memory database provider.

Answer (score 4):

Generally removing something from a cache when the process hasn't finished, can cause troubles. It is not yet sure that the changes will take effect bc your dbms will make that decision for you even when using an orm. You will end up digging into all that exceptions and readd stuff while you could have waited for the process to finish before removing the objects from a given cache.

Other things that came to my mind when I digged a little in your code (which is very clean, +1 for that) are the following

1. Generic-Repository-Pattern is an [anti-pattern](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/). I also like to use it for simple scenarios but it is not really necessary.
2. Your [CacheRepository](https://github.com/ranouf/AspNetCore-Angular-AllInOne/blob/Caching/src/common/AllInOne.Common/Repositories/Cache/CacheRepositoryOfTEntityAndTPrimaryKey.cs) is now not only responsible for caching, it is also reponsible for CRUD operations to the database. This is against the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
3. The [CacheUnitOfWork](https://github.com/ranouf/AspNetCore-Angular-AllInOne/blob/Caching/src/common/AllInOne.Common/UnitOWork/Cache/CacheUnitOfWork.cs) is not only a cache and a unit-of-work, it is also a factory, a repository and yet another layer above functions that are already implemented. Again, this is against SRP.
4. The [IMemoryCache is part of a library the belongs to AspNetCore](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs). You are using it in your own implementations while it is already wrapping a logic that puts stuff into a concurrent dictionary. You could simply use it within a controller, add / update or remove items within your actions when ever necessary.
5. The unit-of-work pattern [in this scenario is not necessary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47904). With your db-context you kinda already have it when using `context.Set<TEnitity>()...` plus wrapping everything inside a repository.

Abstractions are good things but sometimes they can also be very bad.

I know the struggle which is why I read a lot of things about these problems and I came across a good solution. [CQRS](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/05/05/cqrs-with-mediatr-and-automapper/), a mediator and DDD-like services.

I would also recommend to take a look at [AutoFac for IoC and DI](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Lots of things you are doing manually now (like the factory to create types), can be done automatically using its [assembly scanning](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html). It can even be integrated with [.NET Core native IoC](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection).

Hope it helps you to get some ideas.

Comment: Exaclty the kind of comment I was looking for! Thanks a lot.

I will take time to read and follow your suggestions before accept this answer, and maybe other people will add their comments too.

I will probably come back with other questions soon :)

Comment: And yes, I removed the put in cache from CUD in my repository

Comment: I like the fact to only send my  UnitOfWork to my Controller constructor to get my GenericRepository.
So from what you suggest I could do
Constructor(DbContext ctx){
var repo = new GenericRepository(ctx.Set<TEntity>()) }

Something like this?

Comment: You could still do so but instead of creating it manually you can register your types as generic and let your ioc container do the work. Native IOC would be services.AddScoped(typeof(IGeneric<>), typeof(Generic<>)); for instance.